# What is the most "hardworking" letter in the English alphabet?

Tags: orthography, silent-letters

I hope I am not being pedantic; however, I could not come up with an answer on the internet.

> I wonder which is the letter which can be discriminated from the
>   alphabet system on the basis of its myriad uses.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, which it outside the charter of SE sites, so it'll probably be closed, unfortunately.  But the short answer to your question is probably `e`, because it is the most-frequently used letter in English orthography (by a [meaningful margin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:English_letter_frequency_(alphabetic).svg)), it does double-duty as a kind of inflection (think "[*silent e*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_e)"), it sometimes stands-in for schwa, which is the most common vowel *sound* in English, etc.

Comment: All the silent letters, expecially `X`, which has to stand for **everything**.

Comment: @Dan Bron 'A life of _e_'s' doesn't sound like they work too hard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, that's going in my personal pun hall of fame.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, maybe you should try living "the life of rile-e" to see how mistreated they are.

Comment: 'When I make a word do a lot of work like that,' said Humpty Dumpty, 'I always pay it extra.'   Ah, for poor letter e, overworked yet underpaid.

Comment: I think a more interesting/real question would be which letter, if eliminated, would render the most text illegible.  (Arguably vowels can be done away with fairly readily, considering that Hebrew and, I think, some versions of Greek did not have written vowels for a long time, yet did OK.)

Comment: ... I. Without _i_'s, it sounds as if we couldn't read a single sentence.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Without i's we'd have to be a lot more cooperative.

Comment: @HotLicks - Without i's it would be impossible to see anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Dan Bron has put it quite succinctly.

As a Scrabble player, I would tell you that **E** is the most hardworked letter of the English
alphabet.

> Apart from representing its own sound (as in let, send ), it often
>   serves as a silent modifier of others (as in mate, rage).
>
> It is a relic of times when far more English words ended in e – when
>   **“olde shoppe”** was indeed common spelling.  In the course of history, final **e** has come and gone from many words.

Reference- The Cambridge Guide to Australian English Usage by Pam Peters.

Comment: But sinc E is so common, liminating it dosn't rally caus that much difficulty with communication.